# dplyr group by colnames described as vector of strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to group_by multiple columns in my data frame and I can't write out every single column name in the group_by function so I want to call the column names as a vector like so:

```r
cols <- grep("[a-z]{3,}$", colnames(mtcars), value = TRUE)
mtcars %>% filter(disp < 160) %>% group_by(cols) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

This returns error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `mtcars[colnames(mtcars)[grep("[a-z]{3,}$", colnames(mtcars))]]` must be length 12 (the number of rows) or one, not 7
```

I definitely want to use a dplyr function to do this, but can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### Update

`group_by_at()` has been superseded; see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by_all.html. Refer to [Harrison Jones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63402524/3576984) for the current recommended approach.

Retaining the below approach for posterity

---

You can use `group_by_at`, where you can pass a character vector of column names as group variables:

```r
mtcars %>% 
    filter(disp < 160) %>% 
    group_by_at(cols) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
# A tibble: 12 x 8
# Groups:   mpg, cyl, disp, drat, qsec, gear [?]
#     mpg   cyl  disp  drat  qsec  gear  carb     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1  19.7     6 145.0  3.62 15.50     5     6     1
# 2  21.4     4 121.0  4.11 18.60     4     2     1
# 3  21.5     4 120.1  3.70 20.01     3     1     1
# 4  22.8     4 108.0  3.85 18.61     4     1     1
# ...
```

Or you can move the column selection inside `group_by_at` using `vars` and column select helper functions:

```r
mtcars %>% 
    filter(disp < 160) %>% 
    group_by_at(vars(matches('[a-z]{3,}$'))) %>% 
   summarise(n = n())

# A tibble: 12 x 8
# Groups:   mpg, cyl, disp, drat, qsec, gear [?]
#     mpg   cyl  disp  drat  qsec  gear  carb     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1  19.7     6 145.0  3.62 15.50     5     6     1
# 2  21.4     4 121.0  4.11 18.60     4     2     1
# 3  21.5     4 120.1  3.70 20.01     3     1     1
# 4  22.8     4 108.0  3.85 18.61     4     1     1
# ...
```

Answer (score 33):

I believe `group_by_at` has now been superseded by using a combination of `group_by` and `across`. And `summarise` has an experimental `.groups` argument where you can choose how to handle the grouping after you create a summarised object. Here is an alternative to consider:

```r
cols <- grep("[a-z]{3,}$", colnames(mtcars), value = TRUE)

original <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(disp < 160) %>% 
  group_by_at(cols) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())

superseded <- mtcars %>%
  filter(disp < 160) %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(cols))) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop_last')

all.equal(original, superseded)
```

Here is a blog post that goes into more detail about using the `across` function:
https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/

Comment: Am I the only one to have troubles understanding this constant urge of the tidyverse crew to change their interface :-|

Comment: @cmbarbu nope... it's a bit of a headache. `group_by(across(all_of(cols)))` is so ugly and hard to read.

Comment: I'd recommend you guys read the blog post I linked: [https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/). There were four reasons provided why they made the switch which felt pretty reasonable to me.