# Groupby multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyverse

I am trying to create a table with multiple variable

I used `group_by` from the `dplyr` package but it's not giving me what I want.

The example in excel pivot table gives me exactly what I want.

[image: I want something like this excel pivot in R Where I can group multiple variables with observations]

R is not grouping them like excel pivot table instead return per observation.

Here is the code I used to `group_by` then summarise from dplyr package.

```r
Update_Cc_X2 %>%
  group_by(Merchant )%>%
  summarise(Transaction_count = n(), Face_value = sum(FaceValue))
```

Comment: That Excel pivot table isn't grouped by merchant, it's grouped by whatever the `Row Labels` column is named. That's what you need to put in `group_by()`.

Comment: please, read [mcve]

Comment: `dplyr` provides the ability to group_by multiple columns - please reference the question I linked. You just need to provide multiple columns into the `group_by(col_1, col_2, col_3)`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487641/dplyr-groupby-on-multiple-columns-using-variable-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr group by colnames described as vector of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912107/dplyr-group-by-colnames-described-as-vector-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a reproducible example, it is difficult to know for sure, but let's say that your data has columns `Merchant`, `TypeOfMerchant` and `TypeOfTransaction`. Then with `data.table` you can do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(Update_Cc_X2) # convert data.frame to data.table

Update_Cc_X2[, .(Transaction_count = .N, Face_value = sum(FaceValue)), by = .(Merchant, TypeOfMerchant, TypeOfTransaction)]
```

The last line groups and summarizes by the tree variables and creates new summarized variables `Transaction_count` equal to the number of lines (special `.N`) and the sum of the variable `FaceValue`.